# Why isn't log4net logging my stack traces?

Tags: log4net

Using the preferred form of

```
_log.Error("Message", exception)
```

does not log my stack trace. To get around this I have to make sure the .ToString() gets call on the exception by doing the following.

```
_log.Error("Message" + exception);
```

But I know that's wrong, only I can't make the correct version work. Do I need a special line in my log4net.xml file to make this work?

Comment: There is a "StackTrace" in your exception? Put another way: Your exception was thrown, or was simply created and passed to the method "Error"? In the second case (created but not thrown) there will be no Stacktrace.

Comment: Thrown, I tested it by calling throw new Exception("Please give me a trace")

Comment: Did you try to use "exception" "Conversion Pattern Name"? So your "ConversionPattern" should be like this "%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n%exception"

Comment: Now log4net won't log anything. Not regular INFO messages nor exceptions. I'm starting to think my solution is the best way to go

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to provide my eventual answer, just for reference. I had implemented an asynchronous appender scheme for log4net using my answer to the SO question [How do I create an asynchronous wrapper for log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044497/how-do-i-create-an-asyncronous-wrapper-for-log4net)

I noted in my response that you need to be careful about the FixFlags, because anything not in the FixFlags will get dropped from the original logging event. Unfortunately, I did not add FixFlags.Exception to my original solution, so any exceptions generated get dropped during the forwarding process.

Changing my FixFlags from

```
loggingEvent.Fix = FixFlags.ThreadName;
```

To

```
loggingEvent.Fix = FixFlags.ThreadName | FixFlags.Exception;
```

Fixed the issue.